# Rewriting code instead of calling method with same code

Tags: java, arrays, class, methods

In class we were building an expandable array class. While making this we created a method in which you iterated over the array, then later we created another method that used the exact same code to iterate over the list but instead of calling the earlier method we rewrote the same piece of code. When I had asked my professor about why we would rewrite the code instead of calling the earlier method that holds the same code he had said that it comes down to efficiency. How does the efficiency change between rewriting a piece of code and calling a method with the same exact code?

Code from class

```
    private void checkSize(int index){
        if (index >= myArray.length){
            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
    }

    public void set(int index, T obj){

        if (index >= myArray.length){
            reinitalizeArray(index+1);
        }
        myArray[index] = obj;
    }
```

Why would you rewrite the if statement in set when you could do a try catch by calling the checkSize() like so?

```
    private void checkSize(int index){
        if (index >= myArray.length){
            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
    }

    public void set(int index, T obj){

        try{
            this.checkSize(index);
            myArray[index] = obj;
        }catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exception){
            reinitalizeArray(index+1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Providing the code snippet might be easier to 'judge' your situation

Comment: Usually it doesn't make a difference since the compiler does that kind of optimization itself...

Comment: The decision to duplicate code should (almost) never be based on performance - it should be based on whether the two bits of code will always do the same thing and share the same knowledge in the future or not. If the answer is yes then don't duplicate, if the answer is no then you should probably duplicate.

Comment: well, arrays and lists can both be passed by reference hence the code to iterate over either would look the same. but you obviously cannot use the same code to iterate over an array and a list. the code snippet might help in discovering what your professor was referring to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "reuse" variant uses exceptions for flow control.

This is bad practice, Exceptions should be reserved for reporting unavoidable errors, not for simply catching an expected case.

Its also terrible in terms of performance, because if the exception occurs, an Exception object is created and initialized, normal program flow is suspended and the VM starts searching for a matching catch block, then resume excution from there. This also puts more strain on the garbage collection, since the exception will need to be garbage collected later.

The call to checkSize() in your suggestion is also completely superflous, since the assignment `myArray[index] = obj;` would throw the exact same exception if the array were too small.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the *efficiency* is of course better when you reuse you code, because you don't have to rewrite it and you only have to test it once.

The *performance* may be different, depending on the implementation of the list. If it's an ArrayList, it should not change much. If it's another implementation, it could make a huge difference. Lets say you used a LinkedList. Each call of get(index) would iterate over the whole list until the index element was reached while the same call on an array or an ArrayList would directly reference the element and return it. Or lets assume you use a Vector as Implementation. In this case synchronization comes on top.

In Addition, the code will be at least be different in "getting" the elements: array[index] or list.get(index)

Answer (score 0):

The Java code is the same but the generated code will differ. When you use a real type (e.g. List or Vector) the compiled code will contain direct reference to an access method (the []) but when you use exactly the same code with a generic type (Enumeration) the compiled code will contain indirect references as at first must get the real type and at second get the proper access method.
I personally think that in most cases the performance gained in this way does not worth the work. Keep It Short and Simple.